WSL2: Graceful shutdown of MDADM and/or p9 subsystem
I am running MDADM under WSL2 (Ubuntu, kernel: Linux home 6.1.21.2-microsoft-standard-WSL2), and access files from windows applications via standard p9 interface.
Unfortunately, I cannot gracefully stop MDADM when shutting down the system.
After successful "unmount /dev/md0" and trying to stop the array at shutdown (I have both user shutdown script and shutdown task in task scheduler), it seems often p9 keeps files/folders open and prevents mdadm array from stopping :

mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md0: Perhaps a running
process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?.

lsof shows no files in use (as typically I only access files from windows via p9 interface). Eventually windows starts disconnecting disks and mdadm have a fraction of microsecond to mark array faulty on some of the disks.
Any hints on how to force shut it down gracefully?
I would rather prefer to force array stop, and potentially loose data in some open files, but keep array healthy. Currently open files are lost anyways, but in addition I often get broken array on each reboot.

Very interesting - I don't have a solution at the moment, but I'm really curious what your use case is?

@NotTheDr01ds I am on the move, and cannot have my homelab with me. So my windows workstation has to hold my data. I do not like Windows raid, i do like mdadm very much. So I build 8x2Tb mdadm array, and use it in windows for regular data storage tasks. When I am back to my lab - i will just move mdadm inside separate NAS, but it may be years away.
